# Критерий даты в MySQL запросе кратный 3 месяцам и году

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Добрый день, подскажите варианты плиз. В MySQL есть таблица, в ней одно из полей содержит поле типа `datetime`, в котором содержится дата и время.
Раз в час, запускается крон таск, который проверяет либо совпадение текущей даты с временем и даты с временем в базе, либо кратность 7 дням, 3 месяцам и году. Т е если у нас в базе `2017-04-20 15:00:00` то запрос должен срабатывать с 15 до 16 часов каждые 7 дней, 3 месяца и год от этого времени. Минуты неважны.
С днями вопрос реализуется легко:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE (
        hour( `datetime` ) = hour(UTC_TIMESTAMP( ))
    )
    AND (
        MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY , `datetime` , UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ) , 7 ) =0
    )
```

а вот с ``` MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH , ``datetime`` , UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ) , 3 ) = 0 ```
и с ``` MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF( year, ``datetime`` , UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ) , 1 ) = 0 ``` такие фокусы не проходят

Comment: задача про дни тут самая сложная была, или нет? в чем сложность для года проверить помимо часа еще и число и номер месяца?

Comment: про дни как раз самая легкая. Хуже с 3 месяцами. С годом примерно так и борюсь сейчас, только не пойму как с 29 февраля быть...

Comment: сходу для года написал, но тоже промах с високосным годом
 (
hour( `datetime` ) = hour( UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) )
)
AND (
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF( year, `datetime` , UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ) , 1 ) =0
)
AND (
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF( month, `datetime` , UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ) , 12 ) =0
)
AND (
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF( day, `datetime` , UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ) , 365 ) =0
)

Comment: я вообще несколько про другое. Чтобы узнать что дата через год  надо не сам год сравнивать, а `hour`, `day` и `month`, год же останется любым и не будет участвовать в сравнении в принципе.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я вас понял. Но как быть если в базе 2016-02-29 ? Не хотелось бы плодить всякие Ifы

Comment: это уж вам решать. вариантов вроде несколько:не выполнять вообще, выполнить 1.03, выполнить 28.02, либо альтернатива - не давать вообще 29го числа добавлять задачу с цикличностью в год, а при создании переносить ее на 1.03 или 28.02

Comment: А вас устроит если 3 месяца после 31 января - это 30 апреля (так же как и 3 месяца после 30 января). просто пытаюсь вычислить дату запуска подходящую, и оказывается MySQL на `+ interval 3 month` ведет себя именно так и 30 и 31 января дают 30 апреля

Comment: Я тоже озадачился. Если вычесть 3 месяца из 30 апреля, то по моему мнению должно получиться 31 января. Однако команда DATE_SUB('2017-04-30', INTERVAL 3 month) дает 2017-01-30. Хотелось бы получить адекватное решение, с привязкой к последним дням месяца, если задана дата с последним днем в месяце. Собственно, поэтому и обратился на форум.

Comment: Хуже всего с ноябрем. 28, 29 и 30 ноября +3 месяца дают 28 февраля. Какое число вы хотите видеть 30 ноября +3 месяца ? 28 февраля или  2 марта ? Не спешите с ответом, ведь 2 декабря +3 месяца это то же 2 марта и это как бы абсолютно логично. Так какого числа должен произойти следующий 3 месячный запуск для даты 30 ноября. И кстати, что делать если 7 дневный и 3х месячный запуски должны произойти в один день ?

Comment: С ноябрем просто. Либо 28 либо 29 февраля, смотря какой год. А по запускам там так. Поле в таблице будет содержать тип запуска. Т е грубо говоря CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `period` enum('1 DAY','7 DAY','30 DAY','3 MONTH','1 YEAR') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

Comment: Ну и запрос на 7 дней SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE (
 (
`period` =2
)
AND (
hour( `datetime` ) = hour(UTC_TIMESTAMP( ))
)
AND (
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(
DAY , `datetime` , UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ) , 7 ) =0
)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нам надо не проверять по отдельности, часы, дни, месяца и т.п. а убедится что остаток от деления нулевой и  вычислить дату запуска находящуюся на нужном расстоянии от указанной. Выглядеть это будет так (пример для месяца):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
 WHERE MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `datetime`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()+interval 2 day ), 3 )=0
   AND `datetime` BETWEEN 
         `datetime` + interval TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `datetime`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()+interval 2 day ) month
     AND `datetime` + interval TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `datetime`, UTC_TIMESTAMP()+interval 2 day ) month +
          interval 1 hour
```

Внимание: при получении разницы в месяцах к текущей дате добавляется 2 дня. Это делается по той причине, что при сравнении 30 ноября и 28 февраля возвращается разница 2 месяца, хотя именно 28/29 февраля должен произойти 3-месячный запуск.

Есть еще предложение, возможно более универсальное. Добавить в таблицу поле "следующий запуск". При добавлении новой или модификации записи, а так же после каждого запуска в это поле сразу заносится дата следующего запуска. тогда для запуска задач выборка будет с единственным условием

```
`следующий запуск` <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

сразу после запуска к полю "следующий запуск" (не к текущему времени) добавляется требуемый интервал. Такой подход будет гарантировать запуск задачи даже в случае, если сервер не работал в требуемое время. Все задачи будут гарантированно выполнены при следующем старте скрипта. А то будет обидно из за отсутствия электропитания пропустить запуск задачи которая должна выполнятся раз в год...

Comment: Пожалуй, ваше предложение с полем "следующий запуск", будет наиболее простое и наименее затратное. Спасибо вам и teran